# Send Frameset SRC as post request

Tags: html, frameset

```
<FRAME src="someurl">
</FRAME>
```

I need to send the `someurl` as post request. I have tried a lot. Can any one please help me?

Comment: i have my code as this <FRAME src="someurl"></FRAME>

Comment: Have ever heard about AJAX? Please try to google.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't possible. If you are accessing the same domain, then you could use JavaScript (AJAX) to do the post and display the resulting HTML in an iframe (or a div).

If you would give more details it would be much easier to help.